# scala.Array[Long] doesn't conform to expected type scala.Array[java.lang.Long]

Tags: java, scala

I want to mix java code with some scala code, but when try to convert strs to Long Array, error happend. 
Here is my code example :

```
val idsStr:String = "1,2,3";
val ids:Array[java.lang.Long] = idsStr.split(",").map(s=>java.lang.Long.parseLong(s))
```

and error meesage :

```
Error:(11, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : Array[scala.Long]
 required: Array[java.lang.Long]
    val ids:Array[java.lang.Long] = idsStr.split(",").map(s=>java.lang.Long.parseLong(s))
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `java.lang.Long.parseLong` doesn't help you in any way to obtain a `java.lang.Long`, because `parseLong` is a static helper method that returns a primitive (unwrapped) `long`. So, for parsing, you can as well just use Scala's `.toLong`.

What you need is a *cast* to `java.lang.Long` instead, to enforce autoboxing:

```
val idsStr:String = "1,2,3";
val ids: Array[java.lang.Long] = 
  idsStr.split(",").map(_.toLong.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long])
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the constructors of `java.lang.Long`:

```
val ids2: Array[java.lang.Long] = 
  idsStr.split(",").map(str => new java.lang.Long(str.toLong))

val ids3: Array[java.lang.Long] = 
  idsStr.split(",").map(str => new java.lang.Long(str))
```